# Missing model class when build nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package

I have a problem when build a nuget package.There are some classes missing in a reference from nuget. for example:

- Project1 (build nuget for this.)

  - Project2(some model class )

Project1 reference to Project2. When i create a nuget package for the project1, some classes in the project2 missing. I build nuget in TFS, the build config as:

[image]

Please help me solve the problem.

@**Sander Aernouts**. I tried to build solution, but i got an error. The Project2 did not exist. I don't know why. If i build the project1 only, it successfully

[image]

Comment: How's the result when you build the project1 locally? How about build the solution instead of a project? Do you get any error message?

Comment: You may go to the working directory of TFS build agent and build the project1 manually with MSBuild command line to see what result will you get.

Comment: @ Cece. I got an error when build solution, you can check it.

Comment: Have you mapped project2 in the Repository? How's the result if you go to the working directory of TFS build agent and build the solution manually with MSBuild command line?

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot it looks like you are only building on of the .csproj files, not the entire solution:
[image]

This might explain why your project 2 is not build/included. Try building the entire solution instead, so MSBuild can take care of building stuff in the right order. You can then push a pack an publish a nuget package for your .csproj or .nuspec file.

If you still get similar errors open your solution in Visual Studio, right click on your solution and choose `Project Dependencies...` from the context menu. Check that `Project1` has a reference to `Project2` and that the builder is `Project2` and then `Project1`:
[image]

Comment: @ Sander. I add another screenshot, when i build entire solution, i got an error

Comment: @nguyenmy. I updated my answer, could you please verify that the project dependencies and the build order in the solution is right

Comment: @ Sander. I built successfully in VS, but in TFS it throw the error.

Comment: @nguyenmy Are the project dependencies/build order also as shown in the screenshots i added? If these are not right Project1 may build before Project2 which would explain the error you see. There may be numerous reasons why your project builds locally. For instance if you reference project2.dll directly the path to that DLL will be different on the build agent.